# If decimal value, convert to two decimals AND dot separated value to comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have values that look like the following:

```
30
32.5
```

How can I convert these to have two decimals if there is any decimals present (like the 2nd example), AND have the dot delimiter be replaced by a comma?

After the conversion the above numbers would look like this:

```
30
32,50
```

Comment: Different solutions suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431833/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-as-decimal-separator-to-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var num = 32.5;

 num = (num % 1 != 0) ? num.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",") : num;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8J6be/)

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
var num = 32.5;
num = num.toFixed(2).split('.').join();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vxA3e/)

```
var num = 32;
num = (num.toString().indexOf('.') > -1) ? num.toFixed(2).toString().split('.').join() : num;
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vxA3e/2/)

Comment: The second number is perfect. But now the first has decimals as well :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            var a=52;
            var b=44.4;
            a=Number(a.toFixed(2)).toString();
            b=Number(b.toFixed(2)).toString();
            a=a.split(".").join(",");
            b=b.split(".").join(",");
            console.log(a,b)
```