# Convert number in javascript produces NAN

Tags: javascript

I have a text box whose outcome is in Belgium number format like this

```
<input type="text" name="valeurCatalogue" kendo-numeric-text-box="" k-culture='"fr-BE"' k-spinners="{{false}}" ng-disabled="isValueCatalogDisabled" ng-model="tarifForm.Vehicle.valeurCatalogue" />
```

Having put the value as 1525,8 the value gets transformed to 1.525,80 which is correct.

Now if I apply `Number(1525,8)` I get NAN.How to get the number in javascript?

Please note in debug mode I see the value 1525,8 as string.

Comment: Not to remove but replace with dot: Number("1525,8".replace(/,/g, '.'))

Comment: Use `parseFloat("1525,8")` : convert string into float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String with Dot or Comma as decimal separator to number in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431833/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-as-decimal-separator-to-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that javascript uses the american way of expressing numbers (as do most programming languages I've encountered). So, `1,5` is not one and a half as you would expect, rather it's not a valid number. Thus when you try to parse it you get `NaN` (Not a Number). In javascript, the correct way to write said number would be `1.5`. If you have `1525,8` the simple way to do this is replace all commas with dots like this:

```
const numStr = '1525,8';
const replaced = numStr.replace(/,/, '.');
const num = Number(replaced);
```

If however, your number is `1.525,8` you need to first remove the dots (`str.replace(/\./g, '');`).