# Decimal/Float input field with locale format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to solve the following issue:

I got an `<input>` field that is designed for users to enter decimals like `12.5` in their locale-specific format.

In my case: German locale.

In Germany, we are using a comma as decimal separator.

So the input `12,5` should be computed to a model's value of `12.5`.

This is my approach:

```
<template>
        <input
            :id="'form-'+name"
            v-model="displayValue">
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'DecimalField',
    props: {
        value: [String, Number],
    },
    data: () => ({
        innerValue: '',
    }),
    watch: {
        innerValue (newVal) {
            this.$emit ('input', newVal);
        },
        value (newVal) {
            this.innerValue = newVal;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayValue: {
            get: function () {
              return Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE",
                    { style: "decimal" }).format(this.innerValue);
            },
            set: function (modifiedValue) {
                this.innerValue = Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB",
                    { style: "decimal" }).format(modifiedValue);
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

(You may want to tinker around with this on codepen: https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/QWEaYQo ).

** The problem is:**

If you enter 12.5 the value shown in the input is being shown as 12,5 (which is correct in Germany). But if you try to type 12,5, you get NaN.

My question: How can I solve this?

Comment: I think if you modeled your function after this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58631722/2268154 it would work well.